# angular nested modal over items list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-routing

BaseUrl: `/en/products/`

I have: State URL: 
`/en/products/doors?color=red&type=shaped`

This state contains list of items to be sold. Filtered by params.

When I click on one item (name: Red Beech Door, friendlyUrl: red-beech-door) I want modal with item details to be opened and url changed like this:

`/en/products/doors/red-beech-door`

My code app.js:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
        .state('general', {
            url: "/",
            controller: 'productsGeneralController',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/classic.html',
        })
        .state('filter', {
            url: "/:category",
            reloadOnSearch: true,
            controller: 'productsFilterController',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/filter.html',
        })
        .state('filter.concrete', {
            url: "/:product",
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
                $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: "static/templates/pr.html",
                    controller: 'modalProductController',
                });
            }],
        })
});
```

My code in filter.html:

```
<a ng-href="/{{currentCategory}}/{{item.friendlyUrl}}">
...
</a>
```

What I need to achieve:

- display modal over the items listed with this url:  `/en/products/doors/red-beech-door`
- when you close modal, the list would be still in his original unchanged state and url changes to before state `/en/products/doors?color=red&type=shaped`
- also when user click browser's back button the modal closes and url changes to its before state `/en/products/doors?color=red&type=shaped`

I tried to make it with $routeProvider, but then I tried $stateProvider. 
Maybe it's possible to make it via $routeProvider. Please help.

You would make my day if you provide plunker or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

https://lingohub.com/blog/2015/06/bootstrap-modal-window-custom-url-angularjs/

It uses a wrapper on top of the $stateManager to facilitate the registration of modal states and handles the hassle of dealing with the modal. 
Note that it is based on UI Bootstrap modal.